# My Chrome "forget" lots of info everytime I quit

Tags: google-chrome

basically I tried to sign in to bittrex.

Every time I signed in to bittrex bittrex will say that I sign in to new device and have to fill a very annoying email check.

That happens every time the computer is restarted. However, simply restarting chrome produces this effect.

At first I wanted to complain to bittrex. But then I found out web.whatsapp is also like that. Everytime I quite chrome and access web.whatsapp, web.whatsapp will ask me to scan QR code again.

Then the phone would say that I have logged in to 4 browsers and stuffs.

Weird.

As if the google chrome delete all cookies everytime it's restarted.

Comment: Go to `chrome://settings/cookies` and disable "Clear cookies and site data when you close all windows".

Comment: it works. Please turn this into an answer. I got the answer from someone else. Otherwise I'll just answer it and take credit

Comment: Make your mind first :)

Answer (score -1):

https://www.groovypost.com/howto/automatically-delete-browsing-history-chrome/

I did this and it works. Well, I did the reverse of what he is suggesting. I have no idea which idiot turn that setting on.

> Click the More icon  > Settings
>
> Scroll down and click Privacy and security > Cookies and other site
> data  google-chrome-privacy-security-cookies-site-data Toggle the
> setting Clear cookies and site data when you quit
> Chromegoogle-chrome-clear-cookies-when-closed-quit-browser-setting
> Now, whenever you close your Google Chrome browser on your Windows or
> macOS, all cookies will be deleted automatically.

[image]